# Apply formula to every column of dataframe in R

Tags: r

I need to apply a linear regression formula to all the columns in my dataframe called `mydf`. There are thousands of columns in mydf, so indicating each of them would not be possible in the formula. There are two columns, `weight` and `age` which will remain same in the formula for all other columns in which I want to apply this formula.

The formula for first column (column `bmd`) is

```
fit1 <- lm(bmd ~ weight + age, data=mydf)
mydf[,"a"] <-fit1$fitted.values
```

I want to apply this formula to other columns as well (except `weight` and `age`)

```
fit1 <- lm(bp ~ weight + age, data=mydf)
    mydf[,"bp"] <-fit1$fitted.values
```

and

```
fit1 <- lm(choles ~ weight + age, data=mydf)
    mydf[,"choles"] <-fit1$fitted.values
```

what would be the best (time efficient way as it takes really long time) way to expand this formula and store the fitted.values in the right column across all the wanted columns (`bmd`,`bp`,`choles`) ?

mydf

```
bmd  bp   choles    weight  age
1    2    3         22.3     12
2    1    2         33.2     13 
3    2    5         44.5     16
```

Comment: So you want to replace current values of those other columns with regression's fitted values?

Comment: @Parfait yes that is correct. But don't know how to do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
apply(mydf[ ,-c(4:5)], 2, function(x) lm(x ~ mydf$weight + mydf$age)$fitted.values)
```

EDIT: added missing comma

Comment: OP asked for fitted values. Might need to add `$fitted.values`.

Answer (score 0):

One method:

```
# get names of all dependent variables
dependents <- names(df[, -which(names(df) %in% c("weight", "age"))]

# build a little function
myFit <- function(depName) {
  fit1 <- lm(as.formula(paste(depName, "~ weight + age")), data=mydf)
  return(fit1$fitted.values)
}

# sapply them
fittedValues <- sapply(dependents, myFit)
```

Then `cbind` to your dataset.